# Calculating cumulative values for every 12 months on tables with possibly null values

Tags: mysql, date, null, sum

I have this table:

```
Month       Year         MV                    MI         fullDate
-----------------------------------------------------------------
...
5           2015         1                      5         2015-05-01
6           2015         1                     10         2015-06-01
7           2015         3                     10         2015-07-01
8           2015         2                     10         2015-08-01
11          2015         1                     10         2015-11-01
1           2016         4                     10         2016-01-01
6           2016         1                     20         2016-06-01
7           2016         null                  10         2016-07-01
8           2016         2                      5         2016-08-01
...
```

I need to create another table with cumulative values:

```
Month       Year         AMV                  AMI
-----------------------------------------------------------------
...    
7           2015         3                     10
8           2015         5                     20
11          2015         6                     30
1           2016         10                    40
6           2016         11                    60
7           2016         0                     10
8           2016         2                     15
...
```

The cumulative calculations must start on a July and end on June of the next year. In this example, the cumulative fields started "accumulating" from July, 2015 and ended on June, 2016. These calculations re-started on July, 2016 getting another cycle for cumulative values to "calculate"

I made a similar question before but I just found out this "periodicity" for calculations of cumulative. One more thing... some values on the first table could be null and need to be considered as 0.

Please, tell me how can this be done?

Comment: Can you explain how AMV and AMI are calculated?

Comment: For month 7, 2015 MV is 3 so AMV is 3.
For month 8, 2015 MV is 2 so AMV is 2+3 = 5,
and so on until June of next year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified the quer from @Sebastian. The init is also in the query. the counter will reset each year and the **where** is not necessary

```
SELECT 
  (@amv:=IF(MONTH(fulldate)=7,MV, IF(ISNULL(MV), 0, @amv+MV))) AS AMV, 
  (@ami:=IF(MONTH(fulldate)=7,MI, IF(ISNULL(MI), 0, @ami+MI))) AS AMI, 
  fullDate
FROM 
  input
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @amv := 0, @ami := 0) AS init
ORDER BY fullDate ASC;
```

**sample**

```
mysql> select * from input;
+----+------+------+------------+
| id | MV   | MI   | fullDate   |
+----+------+------+------------+
|  1 |    1 |   10 | 2015-08-01 |
|  2 |    2 |   20 | 2015-09-01 |
|  3 |    3 |   30 | 2015-07-01 |
|  4 |    8 |   33 | 2016-07-01 |
|  5 |    2 |    8 | 2016-08-01 |
+----+------+------+------------+
5 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>     SELECT
    ->       (@amv:=IF(MONTH(fulldate)=7,MV, IF(ISNULL(MV), 0, @amv+MV))) AS AMV,
    ->       (@ami:=IF(MONTH(fulldate)=7,MI, IF(ISNULL(MI), 0, @ami+MI))) AS AMI,
    ->       fullDate
    ->     FROM
    ->       input
    ->     CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @amv := 0, @ami := 0) AS init
    ->     ORDER BY fullDate ASC;
+------+------+------------+
| AMV  | AMI  | fullDate   |
+------+------+------------+
|    3 |   30 | 2015-07-01 |
|    4 |   40 | 2015-08-01 |
|    6 |   60 | 2015-09-01 |
|    8 |   33 | 2016-07-01 |
|   10 |   41 | 2016-08-01 |
+------+------+------------+
5 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

Answer (score 1):

This does the trick:

```
SET @amv := 0, @ami := 0;

SELECT 
  (@amv:=IF(ISNULL(MV), 0, @amv+MV)) as AMV, 
  (@ami:=IF(ISNULL(MI), 0, @ami+MI)) as AMI, 
  fullDate
FROM 
  input
WHERE 
  fullDate >= "2015-07-01" AND
  fullDate < "2016-07-01"
ORDER BY fullDate ASC;
```

Comment: The problem is that we expect more entries after 2016-07-01 and we'll need to re-calculate the cumulative values from July, year Y until June, year (Y+1)

Comment: Where is the problem? Just rerun the query every time you get new values. You can either truncate the table and refill it, or set `@amv, @ami` to the last value of that table. If you want to create a view, well I guess thinks get complicated.

Comment: well, maybe that is the complication... they want to see all those cumulative values in a big table

Comment: Well, Do you miss the INSERT? Just add `INSERT INTO table` in front of the select and you get and INSERT SELECT statement. see [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html]